# Identification of $\ell_1^n$ $(\ell_\infty^n)$ with $\ell_\infty^{n^*}$ $(\ell_1^{n^*})$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, isometry, dual-spaces

Let $X=\ell_1^n$ or $\ell_\infty^n$. Then any member of $\ell_1^n$ ($\ell_\infty^n$) can be identified as a functional over $\ell_\infty^n$ ($\ell_1^n$) via the canonical isometric isomorphism $\psi$. What does this identification look like? For example, if $x=(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)\in \ell_1^n$ (or $\ell_\infty^n$) and $\psi(x)=f\in X^{**}$, then what is the action of $f$ on a member of $\ell_\infty^n$ or ($\ell_1^n$)? In other words,

$$ f(u_1,u_2, \dots, u_n)=? \qquad \forall ~(u_1,u_2, \dots, u_n)\in \ell_\infty^n ~or~ (\ell_1^n).$$

Any help will be appreciated. Please refer some credible source!

Comment: Your question is unclear. The  embedding is obvious, not surjective under the axiom of choice. That it is an isometry follows from the definition of operator norm on duals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notation is somewhat confusing. Correct me if I am wrong, but I think with $\ell^n_1$ and $\ell^n_\infty$ you mean the space of sequences of length $n$ equipped with the $1$-norm and the max-norm, respectively? In other words, you consider the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ (assuming the sequences consist of real numbers) equipped either with norm $\|x\|_1=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|$ or with norm $\|x\|_\infty=\max\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. It is well-known that these spaces are equivalent as metric spaces (that is, they are equipped with the same topology).
The notation $\ell^p(X)$ for the space of function on some set $X$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) and bounded with respect to the norm $\|f\|_p:=\left(\sum_{x\in X}|f(x)|^p\right)^{1/p}$, $1\leq p <\infty$, or $\|f\|_\infty=\max\{|f(x)|,\ x\in X\}$ if $p=\infty$, is very common. In view of this, it feels more natural to use the notation $\ell^1_n$ ($\ell^\infty_n$) instead, but I will stick to your notation in this response.

Now, the canonical identification $\psi:X\to X^{**}$ for general Banach space $X$ is given by $[\psi(x)](\Lambda)=\Lambda(x)$ for any $x\in X$ and $\Lambda\in X^*$. In your case $(\ell^n_1)^*$ (or $(\ell^n_\infty)^*$) are equipped with another natural mapping; they can be identified with $\ell^n_\infty$ (or $\ell^n_1$, respectively) via the map
$$
\ell^n_\infty\to (\ell^n_1)^*,\quad y\mapsto \Lambda_y, 
$$
where $\Lambda_y(x):=\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i$ for all $x\in \ell^n_1$. (The map $\ell^n_1\to (\ell^n_\infty)^*$ is defined exactly the same.)
**We do rely on the fact that we are working with a finite-dimensional space $X$. For example, the map $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})\to(\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N}))^*$ is not surjective and therefore cannot be an identification of spaces.**

Finally, any map of Banach spaces $T:X\to Y$ induces the adjoint map $T^*:Y^{*}\to X^*$ via $[T^*(\Lambda)](x):=\Lambda(T(x))$ for any $x\in X$ and $\Lambda\in Y^*$. Returning to your case, the identification $\ell^n_\infty\to (\ell^n_1)^*$ induces the map $(\ell^n_1)^{**}\to (\ell^n_\infty)^*$. Composing this map with the inverse of the other identification map $\ell^n_1\to (\ell^n_\infty)^*$, we get the map
$$
(\ell^n_1)^{**}\to \ell^n_1.
$$
It should be straightforward to check that this map coincides with (the inverse of) the canonical map $\psi$ above; just plug in all the definitions.

This should answer your question as well, but let me write it down explicitly. Let $x=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in \ell^n_1$ and consider the image of $x$ under the canonical map $\psi$, $\psi(x)\in (\ell^n_1)^{**}$. We identify $\psi(x)\in(\ell^n_1)^{**}$ with $f\in(\ell^n_\infty)^*$ (again, via the adjoint of the identification map $\ell^n_\infty\to (\ell^n_1)^*$, $y\mapsto \Lambda_y$). Then,
$$
f(u_1,\ldots,u_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iu_i
$$
for all $u\in \ell^n_1$.

Answer (score 2):

It is well-known that $(\ell^p)^* \cong \ell^{p'}$ where $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p'}=1$ if $p \in [1,\infty)$ by $T: \ell^{p'} \to (\ell^p)^*$, namely, $a=(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty \mapsto T_a$; where $T_a(x):= \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x_n, \quad \forall x = (x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell^p$.

Comment: I have edited "$X=\ell_1^n$ or $\ell_\infty^n$", i.e., my question is only limited to the finite-dimensional context. The answer does not cover the $\ell_\infty^n$, which is fault from my side (which I have edited now). It would be helpful if I get a detailed proof or a reference @alijoohy.